# R: nlme: can we use varIdent or varFixed to model known variances?

Tags: r, mixed-model, variance, generalized-least-squares

Can anyone familiar with `nlme` kindly explain how does the `varIdent`, with option fixed actually work?

Documentation says:

> fixed....an optional numeric vector, or list of numeric values, specifying the values at which some or all of the coefficients in the variance function should be fixed.

What is coefficient in variance function to be fixed? Is it something like variance=kx, where k is the coefficient and x predictor, or variance itself is to be fixed (then it would be strange to use 'coefficient of variance function', unless variance function would be something like varCov=kI, where I is identity matrix).

What I really want to do is to fit a model, where variance is pre-set, a priori known for each value of outcome and was wondering if I can use `varIdent` for this purpose.

**EDIT:** after consulting some literature I understand now that `varIdent` models variance as var=k*var1, where var1 is variance of reference level of given predictor and option 'fixed' allows to pre-specify the values of the coefficient.

Now I would like to know if I can use `varIdent` also to model a priori known, exact values of variances associated with observations of continous outcome at different values of continous predictor, that is, use it to incorporate measurment error in the model.

For example, I have measurments Yobs with SDs ysd, what about model:

gls(Y~X, weights=varIdent(ysd), data=data) ?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you have actual variances for each observation and wish to use these in your nlme model, you can indeed specify these directly using the weights argument in the gls function.

To fit a model with actual variances in nlme, try the following approach:

```
gls(Y ~ X, weights = varWeights(1/variances), data = data)
```

In this model:

`Y` is your outcome variable.
`X` is your predictor(s).
`variances` is a vector containing the actual variances for each observation.
`varWeights` is used to specify the known variances as weights, which should be the inverse of the variances since `gls` uses precision weights (the inverse of the variance).
By specifying `1/variances`, you are incorporating the actual measurement error into the model, and each observation will contribute to the fitting process inversely proportional to its variance.

`varIdent` with the fixed option in `nlme` is used to specify fixed variances for different levels of a categorical factor, scaling the variances by an estimated proportionality constant. It's useful when variances differ across groups but are consistent within them. `varFixed`, on the other hand, assumes that the variance structure is known and constant across all observations, scaled by a single proportionality constant. It applies when you have a uniform variance adjustment factor for the entire dataset. Essentially, `varIdent` allows for group-specific variance scaling, while `varFixed` applies a global scaling factor.

Comment: Thanks, but will it treat the values really as absolute variances,not just proportional weights a la weighted regression? Looking into documentation does not help me to make it clear.

Comment: I agree, the docs are not great to read, but that is my updated understanding! Maybe Ben Bolker will see this, and chime in. He is more of a mixed model expert than I :)

Comment: It would be good he can eventually add his comment. Thank you for your help as well. I was thinking maybe some metaregression package could have this covered as well, but I need compatibility with GAMs.

Comment: Trying the suggested code resulted in error, varWeights requires varFun object as an input

Comment: After some thinking and reading, I think that even using model with just proportions of variance as input, such as with varFix or within classic weighted least square framework might not be such a big problem. Indeed, if there is higher absolute variance in data, this will tend to be reflected in infered variance and in turn in higher standard error of the coefficients, so the estimates will tend to be unbiased ?